# How to search for multiple overlapping occurrences of same word on the same line?

Tags: vim, full-text-search

I want to search for all occurrences of a word on the same line as well as multiple files within a given file. For example:

```
ABCCG*CAT*AD*CAT*TT
DFGBBB*CAT*YYUAB
```

Manually searching for the word `'CAT'` I found two when using `/CAT`, when in fact there are three occurrences of that word in the file.

What is the command to find all occurrences of a given word in a file irrespective of the fact that it may occur multiple times within a line?

Note: There are no `*` in the file. I have used it in the example above to denote the positions of the string `CAT`.

What if the multiple occurrences were to overlap on the same line? For example:

```
ABCCG*TNTNT*ADCATDD
DFGBBB*TNT*YYUAB
```

Searching for the word `TNT` using `:%s/TNT//gn` would still give me 2, when in fact there are three occurrences.

Is there a way to identify overlapping occurrences in the same line using Vim?

Comment: What search plugin are you using as default search doesn't give a count and assuming there aren't any control characters within one of the `CAT's` would find all 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a count of the total number of all matches of an item—including  ”overlapping” string cases, you actually need to use the `%s` command (long form: `%substitute`) and tell it three things:

- do not actually perform the substitution (`n` flag; in this case, a mnemonic for “noop” I guess)
- consider multiple matches on the same line to be separate matches (`g` flag for “global“)
- do a “non-greedy“ match (`\{-}`; somewhat arcane but worth reading up on; see below)

Putting all that together, here's what it looks like:

```
:%s/[T]\{-}NT//gn
```

So, given the following text from the question:

```
ABCCG*TNTNT*ADCATDD
DFGBBB*TNT*YYUAB
```

…vim will then report this:

```
3 matches on 2 lines
```

---

If/when you do actually want a count of just the number of matching lines, you can omit the `g` and vim will use its default of reporting a count just for the number *lines* that contain a match. And if you don’t want to count “overlapping” strings, then omit the `\{-}` part.

---

The vim docs actually have very good info about this stuff.
For more help on counting items in vim, see `:help count-items`:

```
Counting words, lines, etc.                             count-items

To count how often any pattern occurs in the current buffer use the substitute
command and add the 'n' flag to avoid the substitution.  The reported number
of substitutions is the number of items.  Examples:

        :%s/./&/gn              characters
        :%s/\i\+/&/gn           words
        :%s/^//n                lines
        :%s/the/&/gn            "the" anywhere
        :%s/\<the\>/&/gn        "the" as a word

You might want to reset 'hlsearch' or do ":nohlsearch".
Add the 'e' flag if you don't want an error when there are no matches.
```

And for more help with doing “non-greedy“ matching, see `:help non-greedy`:

```
                                                        non-greedy
If a "-" appears immediately after the "{", then a shortest match
first algorithm is used (see example below).  In particular, "\{-}" is
the same as "*" but uses the shortest match first algorithm.  BUT: A
match that starts earlier is preferred over a shorter match: "a\{-}b"
matches "aaab" in "xaaab".

Example                 matches
ab\{2,3}c               "abbc" or "abbbc"
a\{5}                   "aaaaa"
ab\{2,}c                "abbc", "abbbc", "abbbbc", etc.
ab\{,3}c                "ac", "abc", "abbc" or "abbbc"
a[bc]\{3}d              "abbbd", "abbcd", "acbcd", "acccd", etc.
a\(bc\)\{1,2}d          "abcd" or "abcbcd"
a[bc]\{-}[cd]           "abc" in "abcd"
a[bc]*[cd]              "abcd" in "abcd"

The } may optionally be preceded with a backslash: \{n,m\}.
```

Comment: I made an amend to my question. I actually intend to target multiple overlapping occurrences as well. Is there a way to accomplish that in vim? (included another example in my question)

Comment: Ah, yes, OK, that’s easy too—you need to tell vim to do a non-greedy search; something like `:%s/TNT\{-}//gn` should work. I’ll modify my answer to include that.

Comment: @Hello_PG So, getting the right non-greedy match for this case was less easy than I thought; I realized my naive `:%s/TNT\{-}//gn` will match `TN` as well, which we don’t want, so I refined it to `:%s/[T]\{-}NT//gn`, which should give you want you want in this case. (And I like time to get further into detail here about why that works, but I think that really should be what you need.)

Comment: @Hello_PG BTW, this was a good question—upvoted. I hope the answer and the question will end up being useful to others at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @sideshowbarker . However when I try your technique on my actual real-world example I still dont get the answer I am looking for. For example, I am in fact searching for a pattern such as : `CTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTC`, but I get 11 matches on 11 lines, when I should be getting 27 matches on 11 lines.  I tried the following: `%s/[C]\{-}TCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTC//gn`. Did I use it correctly or am I still missing something?

Comment: @Hello_PG So yeah this is why StackOverflow questions should always state exact real cases & not hypothetical ones. So please post that `CTCTCTC…` case as an update to your question. Or rather, to avoid more back-and-forth, please try to post the actual exact real string you want to match (if that `CTC…` one is not actually it; you say “such as” here, so I’m not sure). & of course please also try to post a fragment of the actual text you want to search for it in. & when I have more time I will look back at this & answer again (if somebody else hasn’t already posted a follow-up answer by then).

Comment: I posted [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/substitute-words-enclosed-between-comma-or-open-parenthesis-and-comma-or-closed) on Vi and Vim beta, which is strictly related to the present one. And it's more a real case.